# how to apply pattern on file name to be searched in zgrep command , when variable portion of pattern are non consecutive numbers?

Tags: regex, grep

Using zgrep command i want the list of files containing the string '23230797' (these are compressed .gz files) , eg result files are :

```
/var/log/logfile.DC_8_172.17.80.63.log.2014-12-10-01-PDT.gz
/var/log/logfile.DC_1_172.17.80.63.log.2014-12-01-23-IST.gz
/var/log/logfile.DC_5_172.17.80.63.log.2014-12-30-11-PST.gz
```

NOTE: the variable substring(single digit) above after 'DC_'.
In my case i do not want to user * or ? in place of the the digit , because i already know the digits of files in which i want to search the string i want my search to target the specific files which i specify.

```
    zgrep -l 23230797 /var/log/logfile.DC_5_172.17.80.63.log.2014-12*
```

Comment: Do you mean just the single digit x, where DC_x_172 or are there other strings to search for?

Comment: just a single digit x , and the last few characters of the file name are variable which are handles using *

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell glob:

```
zgrep -l 23230797 /var/log/logfile.DC_[0-9]_172.17.80.63.log.2014-12*
```

`[0-9]` will match any digit after `DC_`.

To search for specific files use:

```
zgrep -l 23230797 /var/log/logfile.DC_[815]_172.17.80.63.log.2014-12*
```

---

**EDIT:** Answering a question asked in comments:

> what if the pattern contains a combination of 'specific' single and double digit number like `DC_22_` , `DC_1_`

You can use `extglob` in BASH:

```
shopt -s extglob
zgrep -l 23230797 /var/log/logfile.DC_@(22|1)_*
```

Comment: zgrep -l 23230797 /var/log/logfile.DC_[815]_172.17.80.63.log.2014-12* , i have not tried this one but i think this is my answer , can you also tell me what in case if the file names i want to search for has combination of both single and double digit numbers or even numbers with greater than 2 digits.

Comment: For 2 digits you can use: `zgrep -l 23230797 /var/log/logfile.DC_[0-9][0-9]_172.17.80.63.log.2014-12*`

Comment: what i mean in my previous comment is what is the pattern contains a combination of 'specific' single and double digit number like DC_22_ , DC_1_ etc , note:i do not want to search all available files , only files with specific numbers(1 , 22 etc) in their names are required to be searched .